# How can I get Container Logs using Golang? (Error)

Tags: docker, go, logging, monitoring

I am trying to code a Docker Monitoring software in Golang.

my Code looks as followed:

```golang
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "time"

    "github.com/docker/docker/api/types"
    "github.com/docker/docker/client"
)

func main() {
    ctx := context.Background()

    cli, err := client.NewClientWithOpts(client.FromEnv)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    containers, err := cli.ContainerList(ctx, types.ContainerListOptions{})
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    for _, container := range containers {
        out, err := cli.ContainerLogs(ctx, container.ID, types.ContainerLogsOptions{
            ShowStderr: true,
            ShowStdout: true,
            Timestamps: false,
            Follow:     true,
            Tail:       "40"})

        if err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }

        fmt.Println("The \"" + container.Image + "\" container, with the ID \"" + container.ID + "\" logged: ")
        fmt.Println()

        buf := new(bytes.Buffer)

        fmt.Println(buf.ReadFrom(out))

        fmt.Println(buf.String())
    }
    time.Sleep(time.Second * 3)
}
```

The problem is that the execution of the above code stops on the `fmt.Println(buf.ReadFrom(out))` statement. The code used to work, but it suddenly just doesn't anymore. Either it stops without an error, or it returns an empty String.

The client I am trying to collect the logs from is also coded by myself, and it looks like follows:

```golang
package main

import (
    "log"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    for i := 0; i > -1; i++ {
        log.Output(1, "Hello World logged!")
        time.Sleep(time.Minute)
    }
}
```

I already tried debugging and checking Variables, but I just can't get to the source of the Problem.

Comment: `Either it stops with an error, or it returns an empty String` ... `I already tried debugging and checking Variables, but I just can't get to the source of the Problem`. Getting to the source is going to be harder for anyone else if you don't tell us what error you get, what are the debugging steps you have already taken, and what exact behavior you expect instead. Please read [ask] paying attention to the [mre] section. Then [edit] your question to add the missing bits. Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am really not sure as I don't have any error logs to confirm my hypothesis.
But could it be the case that as the ContainerLogs returns a stream (io.ReadCloser), maybe the stream itself hasn't closed yet?

If this is a possibility, you can either do a dry run first to test out this theory by adding a timeout and logging it after every small duration ?

one possible way to do this is

```
    select {
case <-time.After(5 * time.Second):
    fmt.Println("Timeout exceeded while reading container logs")
case <-ctx.Done():
    fmt.Println("Context cancelled while reading container logs")
case b := <-out:
    if b != nil {
        buf.Write(b)
    }
}
```